# a single vim command for "edit a new file" or "switch to existing buffer"?

Tags: vim

**Problem**:
If the file "tmp.rb" has been modified, the command "e tmp.rb" will fail.

I'm seeking for a command to succeed in both following conditions:

- If "tmp.rb" is not in the buffer list, the file will be loaded;
- If "tmp.rb" is already in the buffer list and been modified, the
  buffer will be loaded(in current window).

---

**Clarification**:
Sorry for all the misleadings. Indeed a single command `e tmp.rb` will achive both as long as the modified "tmp.rb" is not loaded into the current window, *in which situation* I prefer `e tmp.rb` does not cause an error and has the same effect as `b tmp.rb`. Maybe this little concern will make scripting around buffers, windows etc. a little more easily.

Comment: If the file currently loaded has been modified, then `:e tmp.rb` will fail, but `:e! tmp.rb` works.  Is `tmp.rb` the name of the current buffer also?

Answer (score 1):

The `:edit` command fails when the buffer is already loaded and modified to prevent you from accidentally overwriting the changes. If you do want to override, use `:edit!` instead. In many Vim commands, an appended bang (`!`) forces the command. Alternatively, if you want Vim to ask you for confirmation, use `:confirm edit`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your problem.

What I do to try reproduce your problem is

1. Open tmp.rb with vim, write some thing and save.
2. In other shell,

   ```
   $ echo > tmp.rb
   ```
3. Enter `:e` or `e: tmp.rb` in vim and it reopen the file without any problem.

If other program is accessing the tmp.rb at the same time this other program maybe are locking the file and because of it you are having the trouble you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question says "OR" but its body says "AND".

Vim's commands are usually very precise, it's rare to see an ambiguous command that does multiple mutually exclusive things. The number of keys you can use to enter *insert* mode (`iaIAsScCoO`) is a perfect example of this.

You should use the appropriate command for each situation:

```
:e tmp.rb
:b tmp.rb
```

---

If you don't mind installing plugins, [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim)'s `:CtrlPMixed` may help you with its nice abstraction.